# R - Squared Pie chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, pie-chart, finance

Need help to get my pie chart displayed like this:

[image]

As you can see a square proportion is drawn using a given percentage. I'm trying to plot an industry's weigths (10 variables).

Here is my DF:

```
     BUSD     USDC      DAI    GEMINI      HUSD       PAX     STASIS       UST     USDT       TRU
1 11.70257 37.16381 4.529632 0.1128532 0.1778291 0.6171099 0.02256854 0.3773179 44.49382 0.8024782
```

I'm open to any solutions, but i need percentages and TitleS inside each box.

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a treemap, you can do one with the `treemapify` library and `ggplot2`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
#install.packages("treemapify")
library(treemapify)

pivot_longer(df, everything()) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(area = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_treemap() +
  geom_treemap_text(aes(label = paste(name, paste0(round(value, 2), "%"), sep = "\n")), colour = "white") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mael, it helps me a lot :) Can you help me to display percentages please ?

Comment: This is probably because you have not the same data frame that the one you put in the question. Check the documentation to know what’s wrong

Comment: Indeed, all good now :)